# Webpack & dependencies : not the same type between packages for the same reference redux-form (instanceof not working)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux-form

I'm using redux-form in two of my packages.
I have a ref : PackageA > PackageB

When I throw a SubmissionError (from redux-form) in PackageB, it is not catched as SubmissionError in PackageA.

If i check "error instanceof SubmissionError" in my packageA (when error is catched from PackageB), it return false.

The two package have the same version of redux-form.

Where is the problem ?